# Change the maximum number of records to be displayed in a specific subpanel in SugarCRM 7

Tags: limit, sugarcrm

In SugarCRM 7.9 how we can change the maximum number of records to be displayed in a specific subpanel.

In Developer guide i have found that by changing the 'list_max_entries_per_subpanel' limit in config override we can change the records display limit for all subpanels but i want to have the effect only in my specific subpanel for example Contacts subpanel available in Accounts module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was interested to find out the answer to this too, so I did some digging and figured this out. As per your example of displaying a different number in the Contacts subpanel in Accounts, here's what you can do:

Add the following file to custom/modules/Contacts/clients/base/views/subpanel-list/subpanel-list.js

```
({
    extendsFrom: "SubpanelListView",

    initialize: function(options){
        this._super("initialize", [options]);
        if (this.context.get("parentModule") == "Accounts"){
            this.context.set("limit",1);
        }
    }
})
```

If you'd like to know more specifically what's going on, I'll elaborate. Here's a breakdown of what's happening:

1. State that you're extending the standard subpanel list view.
2. Override the parent class' initialize function.
3. Call the parent initialize function (to ensure all superclass behaviour is respected)
4. If this (Contacts) subpanel has a parent module of Accounts (i.e. this subpanel is one of the ones displayed below the Accounts record view), then set the context property "limit" to the desired value.

I've tested this successfully by linking 3 contacts to an Account, and it only displayed 1, and subsequently linked 3 contacts to an Opportunity, and it showed all 3.